# Irrelevant Glassfish Exception

Tags: java, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, netbeans-6.9

I'm facing with very weird problem in NetBeans IDE 6.9.1 and GlassFish 3. 
Just after installing NetBeans over windows Seven with 64 bits JDK and without creating any project I start GlassFish server and get following error !!!

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
<local>*|localhost|127/0/0/1|MyPCName
Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
<local>*|localhost|127.0.0.1|MyPCName
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class:
<local>*|localhost|127.0.0.1|MyPCName.
Program will exit.
```

It worked fine in same system and suddenly I got the error! After that even uninstalling NetBeans and GlassFish and installing them in other drive did not solve the problem.

Comment: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=174583 - This can shed some light

Comment: many thanks, it made me note to the 'use IDE proxy' check-box when I was trying to use another Java Executable :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I think I found the solution! 
By right click over 'GlassFish Server 3' item under Servers in Services tab and selecting properties the server window will be opend.
In Java tab of opened window, there is a check-box says 'Use IDE's proxy setting' which is checked by default and I believe as I had proxy setting in my system which by default uses as IDE proxy this strange problem occurred.
Anyway deselecting the check-box solved the problem!!